# fundamental group of moduli spaces of sheaves

Tags: moduli-spaces, ag.algebraic-geometry

I am considering moduli spaces of sheaves on irreducible holomorphic symplectic manifolds.
I haven't seen a general theory to describe the fundamental group of moduli spaces of sheaves yet. Is there such a theory? What does it mean to have a loop in such a space? Is there any connection to nonabelian Hodge theory?

Comment: Dear Malte, it's probably a good idea to add a more general relevant tag to your question, say ag.algebraic-geometry. That way, people who only read questions with that tag will see it too.

Answer (score 1):

I also was thinking about homotopy groups of stacks of sheaves.  There are two ways I could think of to approach this.

The first is to take the algebraic stack or space and associate to it a topological stack or space.  If its a topological space then you can take its homotopy groups.  Then homotopy groups of a topological stack are also defined (see papers of Noohi).

The second way is more vague.  One could say a map from any topological space $T$ to the stack of sheaves on $X$ is a sheaf of vector spaces on $X \times T$ such that over each point in $T$ it is a coherent sheaf on $X$ with the appropriate restrictions.  But then one wants it to be flat over $T$ somehow.  Once this is defined you can define homotopy groups in the usual way.  They are not going to be sets though unless you mod out by some isomorphisms between sheaves.